# Nested TabNavigation inside stack not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-dom, react-native-web

Tab Navigation inside a stack navigation is not working when tab screen is not the initial route of the stack. Tab buttons are not switching screens. In Case TabsScreen is the initial route of the stack navigation tabs works fine. Code is as below,

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button, Platform} from 'react-native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
```

Navigation config,

```
const navigationConfig = (showHeader = false) => {
    const options = {
        animation: 'timing',
        config: {
            duration: 330,
            stiffness: 1000,
            damping: 500,
            mass: 3,
            overshootClamping: true,
            restDisplacementThreshold: 0.01,
            restSpeedThreshold: 0.01,
        },
    };
    return {
        headerShown: showHeader,
        gestureEnabled: false,
        lazy: true,
        animationEnabled: true,
        transitionSpec: {
            open: options,
            close: options,
        },
    };
};

const drawerConfig = (showHeader = false, drawerType = 'front') => {
    const options = {
        animation: 'timing',
        config: {
            duration: 330,
            stiffness: 1000,
            damping: 500,
            mass: 3,
            overshootClamping: true,
            restDisplacementThreshold: 0.01,
            restSpeedThreshold: 0.01,
        },
    };
    return {
        headerShown: showHeader,
        lazy: true,
        drawerType: drawerType,
        gestureEnabled: true,
        animationEnabled: true,
        drawerStatusBarAnimation: 'fade',
        useLegacyImplementation: true,
        transitionSpec: {
            open: options,
            close: options,
        },
    };
};
```

Nested navigations as below,

```
const DrawerStack = () => {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator
            // screenOptions={drawerConfig()}
            // keyboardDismissMode={'on-drag'}
            useLegacyImplementation={Platform.OS === 'web'}
    >
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={AppStack} />
        <Drawer.Screen name='Tab1' component={Tab1} />
        <Drawer.Screen name='Tab2' component={Tab2} />
        <Drawer.Screen name='Tab3' component={Tab3} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
    )
}

const AppStack = () =>{
    return(
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={navigationConfig()}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={TabsScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}


const TabsScreen = () =>{
    return(
        <Tab.Navigator 
        // screenOptions={navigationConfig()}
        >
            <Tab.Screen name='Tab1' component={Tab1} />
            <Tab.Screen name='Tab2' component={Tab2} />
            <Tab.Screen name='Tab3' component={Tab3} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}
```

HomeScreen for initial route

```
const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) =>{
    return(
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'gray', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Home</Text>
            <Button title='go to ' onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Tabs')}/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Sample tab screens as below,

```
const Tab1 = ({navigation, state}) =>{

    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Tab 1</Text>
            <Text>Tab 1</Text>
            <Button title='go to ' onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Tab2')}/>
        </View>
    )
}

const Tab2 = ({navigation}) =>{
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Tab 2</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const Tab3 = ({navigation}) =>{
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Tab 3</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

App.js code as below,

```
const App = () =>{
    return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="InStack" component={DrawerStack} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>);
}

export default App;
```

Dependencies,

```
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.11",
    "react-native-web": "^0.18.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.8.0",
    "webpack": "^5.85.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.0"
```

Thanks in advance!